# Implementing message handler in TypeScript using mapped types

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I'm attempting to implement a message handler by leveraging mapped types. The issue is that the `handleMessage` function below does not compile. I understand why it doesn't type check, but I think this is a reasonable use case. Is it even possible to implement `handleMessage` or similar in TypeScript?

```
type Message = { id: "A", value: string } | { id: "B", value: number };
type MessageIds = Message["id"];
type MessageCase<K extends MessageIds> = Message & { id: K };

type MessageHandler<K extends MessageIds> = (message: MessageCase<K>) => MessageCase<K>;

type MessageHandlers = {
    readonly [K in MessageIds]: MessageHandler<K>;
}

const messageHandlers: MessageHandlers = {
    A(message: MessageCase<"A">): MessageCase<"A"> {
        return {
            id: "A",
            value: message.value.toUpperCase(),
        };
    },

    B(message: MessageCase<"B">): MessageCase<"B"> {
        return {
            id: "B",
            value: message.value * 2,
        };
    },
};

function handleMessage<K extends MessageIds>(message: MessageCase<K>): MessageCase<K> {
    return messageHandlers[message.id](message);
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if this article is helpful https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe

Comment: Not really. The key point here is to be able to do this without checking for each case manually.

Comment: MessageCase is wrong, because `const x: MessageCase<'A'> = {
  id: 'A',
  value: '1'
}`

Comment: How so? I tried that code and it compiles just fine.

Comment: My bad) it work

Comment: This is yet another case of the compiler's inability to handle what I've been calling "correlated union types"; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  You'll have to use something like a type assertion to get this to compile, where the burden of enforcing type safety shifts from the compiler (which can't do it here) to you (so be careful).  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3AXyw).